# Is this iOS app using segmented control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

In this photo (AirBnB iOS app), where it saids Upcoming and Previous, what do you guys think how this is implemented? Do you guys think this is developed using segmented control or two different buttons reversing (on/off, off/on) each other? 
Is there an easy way(preferably using Swift) or a library to implement this feature in the app? 
Sorry if this is a very naive question. It's my 3rd day learning iOS development :Face With Tears Of Joy:

[image]

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: This is possible using segment control but you have to customise it..

Comment: Its look like segement control, but without showing code we cant 100% sure, its segmented control or button ? So please show your some code here!!!!

Comment: I think he can't show code because in the question he is saying that is a screehshot from Air BnB app. He is asking if the control used in this screens are segmented controls.
Anyway I agree with previouses comments: without source code is quite hard to say what is used. They can use buttons, toolbar and other controls to mimic segments..

Comment: I don't have a code of course. This is an airbnb app, not my own. I just want to know how this kind of functionality could have been implemented and best way, in your opinion, to implement the same functionality.

Comment: It could be a segmented control but customized using `appearance` proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *right answer* since we don't have the source code.

However it could be one of those proposition :

- Using a `UISegmentedControl` and customize it's appearance ;
- Using two `UIButton` and change there appearance depending on which one is currently selected ;
- Creating your own component : `IBDesignable` (that you'll be able to see directly while building your interface).

Since you are at your *3rd day learning iOS development*, you might want to give a look at all the proposition above.

The `IBDesignable` solution could be the better one. Indeed, if you build it properly you would be able to reuse it easily on different screen size and in multiple apps. But, it might not be easy for you to create it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably a segmented control. You can having something like the following:

```
UIImage *segmentSelected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected =
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected =
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected =
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected
forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected
forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]
setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Quoted from RayWenderlich:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6